# Executing multiple statements with SQLiteDatabase.execSQL

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've followed a standard tutorial for building a database with Android.  I've created a class called DbHelper which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.  I've Overridden the create handler to execute a string.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DbDefinitions.DB_CREATE);
}
```

DbDefinitions.DB_CREATE is a static String I've created.

```
public static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "messages";
public static final String TABLE_FRIENDS = "friends";

public static final String STATE_OK = "STATE_OK";

public static final String DB_CREATE = 
    "create table " + TABLE_MESSAGES + " (_id integer primary key, user_id integer not null, created_on integer, subject text not null, summary text not null, messagetext text null, read integer not null, status text not null default '" + STATE_OK + "'); " +
    "create table " + TABLE_FRIENDS + " (_id integer primary key, user_id integer not null, friend_id integer not null, created_on integer, status text not null default '" + STATE_OK + "');";
```

I'd like to use 1 String to execute multiple SQL statements.  How can I do this as SQLiteDatabase.execSQL only allows 1 statement?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's not possible to do using the standard methods which comes with Android. So, if you want to execute *batch* of multiple SQL statements, you will have to create your own utility to do so. For instance, you can have something like this:

```
public void executeBatchSql(String sql){
    // use something like StringTokenizer to separate sql statements
    for each sql statement{
        database.execSQL(oneStatement);
    }
}
```

Though, what I'd do is something like this:

```
String sql1 = "create bla bla bla;";
String sql2 = "create foo bar;";
String[] statements = new String[]{sql1, sql2};

// then
for(String sql : statements){
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Comment: what if the ';' is within a text field?

Comment: The **;** at the end of the SQL statements is completely useless.

Answer (score 20):

Well, in my case, I am excuting queries from a file which I saved as an asset
This is the solution I used+-

```
String script = readAsset(CREATE_SCRIPT);//readAsset is a method i use to get the file contents
try {
     String[] queries = script.split(";");
 for(String query : queries){
        db.execSQL(query);
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    .....
```

**EDIT**

In my case, the Queries were simple insert queries which I had full control over. However, the issue has been raised concerning queries with ";" inside them.

@TWiStErRob suggests using

```
script.split(";$");// $ meaning end of line. You will need to use RegexOption.MULTILINE for this to work
```

or

```
script.split(";\n");// but you will need to ensure that each query is on a different line
```

Comment: i'm new to Java and Android development but your solution may fail on the line script.split() if your stored statements contains a semicolon as part of a text value (e.g. on the default value of a column definition)

Comment: You are definitely right about that. I don't think it is a java or android thing, but rather a regex problem. I am no regex guru so I can't give you the exact thing, but using a regex which checks if the semi-colon is at the end of the statement should work. This works for me as my script is mainly to create the various tables.

Comment: @frostymarvelous Ops.. sorry!

Comment: @jon @Seraphim @frostymarvelous `script.split(";$")` would do, `$` meaning end of line, or if you're not a regex fan you can use `script.split(";\n")`, but then you have to make sure it's a file/string with unix line endings! Though parsing SQL strings is not a good idea (some well-known frameworks do it, and sadly got it wrong). Without a real parser (ANTLR) there's always an exception to work around.

Comment: It's necessary to add that in order for `;$` to work, you should use `RegexOption.MULTILINE` option for your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    try {
        InputStream is = this.context.getAssets().open("script.sql");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("SQL Script", line);
            if (!line.isEmpty() && !line.trim().startsWith("--"))
                db.execSQL(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SQL Script", e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.i("SQL Script", "script executed");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of SQLiteDatabase and my experience in the past I think that it's not possible. But why don't you just split it up in single statements? It really is not a problem in your example. Or do you need it for a different use case?

Answer (score 0):

we have many greate answers here.
and here is my solution for multiple insert statements, however I used a file in assets not in row, each line in this file is an insert statement.

```
    try {
        in = getAssets().open("InsertStatemets.SQL");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null){
            db.execSQL(line);
            Log.e("Insert Statement",  line); 
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```