# How do I convert an SQL file into a .db file in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sql file made with DB Desktop for SQLite for android.

I need this .sql file to be a .db file so I can copy it into an empty database.

I have the .sql file saved in assets in my android project, I basically can't see any way to convert this to the .db type. I don't want this to be on a server, I just want a local .db file for android.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can follow this answer for solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199138/android-how-to-exec-a-sql-file-in-sqlitedatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199138/android-how-to-exec-a-sql-file-in-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: Thanks, this did answer my question!