# sqlite bulk insertion from text file in assets

Tags: android, text-files, android-sqlite, bulkinsert, android-assets

I am facing a problem in case while I am having a bulk of insert queries in my text file (stored in assets), I do want to execute all those queries while installation of app after creation of tables.

I am unable to understand how to do this.

I have the following code, that executes **only the first one** of all queries.

```
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     //create table queries

     // inserting from the text file in assets

   InputStream in_s = cntx.getAssets().open("VistaLog.txt");
   byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
   in_s.read(b);
   String sql = new String(b);
   db.execSQL(sql);

  }
```

But, I do need to execute all queries one by one.

**Update**

Using this code

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
try {
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("VistaLog2.txt");
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            char[] chars = new char[8192];
            for(int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0;) {
                // process chars.
                sb.append((char)len);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("chunkfile", "error here: "+e.getMessage());
        }    


   String[] queries = sb.toString().split(";");
    for(String query : queries){

        Log.d("vista_database", "query: "+query);
           db.execSQL(query);
        }
```

Gives me the following error.

```
  08-07 16:33:06.187: E/Database(8115): Failure 1 (near    
  "                                                                                        
    ᆱ": syntax error) on 0x2a2ba8 when preparing 
  '                                                                                     
 ᆱ'.

  08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  near "                                                                                     ᆱ":  
  syntax error:                                                                                      ᆱ

 08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):    at  
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)

 08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):    at 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1836)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at com.Vista.Helper.DataHelper$OpenHelper.onCreate(DataHelper.java:1140)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at com.Vista.Helper.DataHelper.<init>(DataHelper.java:105)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at com.bus_service.Vista_bus_service.onCreate(Vista_bus_service.java:64)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4628)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:879)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:637)
08-07 16:33:06.217: E/vista_database(8115):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible with SQlitedatabse methods in android for this you have to repeat the loop

may be this will helpful for you.

[batch operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805938/executing-multiple-statements-with-sqlitedatabase-execsql)

try to read the text from the file like this it will give correct data

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    int i;
    try {
        inputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets()
                .open("readme.txt");
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
```

Comment: I have tried to use the last one of given answers, but thats giving me the following error.08-07 16:08:30.557: E/Database(1879): Failure 1 (near "                                                ๶": syntax error) on 0x2a1118 when preparing '                                                ๶'.
08-07 16:08:30.587: E/vista_database(1879): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "                     ๶": syntax error:                                                 ๶

Comment: that means the sql statement what you are given is syntactically wrong..check it ones..

Comment: INSERT into StopMaster(stopId,stopName,routeId,sequenceId,filePath) values(2509,'CSUCI [11:25 AM]',442,3,'');

INSERT into StopMaster(stopId,stopName,routeId,sequenceId,filePath) values(2510,'CSUCI [11:30 AM]',443,1,'');

INSERT into StopMaster(stopId,stopName,routeId,sequenceId,filePath) values(2511,'"C" St [11:55 AM]',443,2,'');

INSERT into StopMaster(stopId,stopName,routeId,sequenceId,filePath) values(2512,'"C" St [3:00 PM]',444,1,'');

Comment: This was the sample I do have in my text file. Now wnen I try to read it through Reader class, and further executing it gives me the above mentioned error.

Comment: It clearly showing there is syntax error in your sql command here syntax error) on 0x2a2ba8 when preparing                                                                                    
 ᆱ'. that character is not understandable that's why it is giving error

Comment: The queries are similar to the ones I posted in above comment. and works very well when I execute them without using the text file Though, they are in bulk, I guess may be the problem

Comment: from your code the error is coming from when you are reading the data from the assets by using buffers it is giving you different symbols once verify the data after reading from the text file