# Sqlite multiple statement with semi colon not working from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I have to update multiple statement in sqlite database from my iOs app. for that I have written following string.

```
query = @"UPDATE channels set sts = 'A' , isowner = '1' WHERE channelid=6798;UPDATE channels set sts = 'A' , isowner = '1', srl = '175' WHERE channelid=6795;";
NSLog(@"query %@",query); 
[dbManager executeQuery:query];
```

I have create a string/statment as string with semi colon. It is worked perfectly in sqlite browser/editor, but not working in iOS app. It not throwing any error while executing statement. I don't find any mistake in my code. (as per my best knowledge). Can someone help me, why it is not working? 
Thanks.

Comment: tried executing by seperating the query ?

Comment: Execute one by one query.

Comment: @UmairAfzal,  Bhadresh-Mulsaniya, thanks for reply. one by one is working fine, but taking much more time. I have written only 2 statement for example, but in real time this is more then 50 statement.

Comment: try to put these quries in an Array and then execute using loop

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805938/executing-multiple-statements-with-sqlitedatabase-execsql) I think SQlite behaves the same way in IOS

Answer (score 3):

I have searched and solved it using this:

```
- (BOOL)executeBatch:(NSString *)sql error:(NSError**)error
{
    char* errorOutput;

    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;

    // Set the database file path.
    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

    BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);

    if(openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int responseCode = sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorOutput);

        if (errorOutput != nil)
        {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:errorOutput]
                                         code:responseCode
                                     userInfo:nil];
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```